# For a representation of a lie group, the subset of points invariant with repsect to a given linear space is a closed subspace.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

This question from a previous paper of an exam I am studying for.

Let $G$ be a lie group. Let $\pi$ be a continuous representation of $G$ in $V$ a finite dimensional complex linear space. Let $W$ be a linear subpsace of $V$. 
Show that $H:=\{x\in G: \pi(x)W \subset W\}$ is closed in $G$.

I'm very stuck trying to tackle this question. If we restrict $\pi$ to $H$ then it gives that $W$ is invariant, but I cannot see how this helps.

Comment: To show a topological property, it's probably wise to make use of the fact that $\pi$ is continuous. What is your definition for continuity of a representation? Because with the right setup, this might just follow from the fact that $E_W := \lbrace e \in End_{\mathbb C}V: e(W) \subseteq W \rbrace$ is a subspace of the finite-dimensional vector space $End_{\mathbb C} V$ (hence closed in its natural topology).

Comment: I think I use $\pi$ is continous if it is continuous in the usual sense as a map from $G\times V \rightarrow V$. I'm not sure how $E_W$ relates to $H$. Is it that for every $x\in G$ we have $\pi(x) \in End_C V$?

Comment: An alternative way to do this: Pick a basis for $W$ and extend it to a basis for $V$. What do the matrices $\pi(x)$ with $x\in H$ look like in this basis?

Comment: Milkman: OK. Well, $\pi$ induces (or is equivalent to) a group homomorphism $ \tilde{\pi}: G \rightarrow GL(V)$. If one can show that this map is continuous as well, where the RHS gets the subspace topology of $End_{\mathbb C} V$, then one can conclude about $H = \tilde{\pi}^{-1}(E_W \cap GL(V))$. (When written out as matrices, this more or less boils down to @TobiasKildetoft's hands-on approach I think.)